# 404 error in gwt project- servlet is correctly defined in web.xml but still getting 404 error

Tags: gwt, gwt2

I am working to create a web app using GWT+Java backend. The host page is "App.html"
The app also has a RPC, and the host page when initially loaded, makes an RPC call.

However this is the message I am getting from Javascript console in Google Chrome browser-

```
POST http://app.sparkcrawler.com/com.arvindikchari.auth.App/AuthenticationService 404(Not Found)
```

Given below are the contents of my web.xml--

```
<?xml version................................>
    <servlet>
    <servlet-name>AuthenticationService</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.arvindikchari.auth.server.AuthenticationServiceImpl</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>AuthenticationService</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/com.arvindikchari.auth.App/AuthenticationService</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

What am I doing wrong here? How do I resolve this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with your servlet mapping.

Basically, you have two things in web.xml (regarding servlets):

- the `<servlet>` tag, which defines the alias for the servlet, and its
  fully-qualified name (In your case AuthenticationService and com.arvindikchari.auth.server.AuthenticationServiceImpl)

  the `<servlet-mapping>` which specifies a url-pattern for a given alias
  (taken from the `<servlet>` definitions).

It should be like

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>AuthenticationService</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/authenticationService</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your servlet mapping url pattern looks wrong.

normally when mapping any servlet `<url-pattern>` would be like this.

```
<`<url-pattern>/{app name}/{servlet name}</url-pattern>`
```

here app name would be same as registered app name which is in gwt.xml file.